# Имена собственные

Tags: морфология

1) Можно ли определить склонение составного собственного имени существительного, если его первая часть представляет прилагательное?

2) Отвечает составное собственное имя существительное на единый вопрос - "что?" или "Александровский", "Великая Отечественная" рассматриваются отдельно при морфологическом разборе?

Например: Александровский пост, Великая Отечественная война.

Answer (score 1):

Я не вполне понимаю, что вы имеете в виду под "склонением составного собственного имени существительного". У него нет самостоятельного типа склонения, каждая из его частей имеет собственный тип - тот же, что имела и вне сочетания. Так, в названии города "Сухой Лог" "Сухой" склоняется по первому типу для прилагательных, а "Лог" - по второму типу для существительных, как это было бы, если бы эти слова употреблялись отдельно в другом контексте.

Второй ваш вопрос требует уточнения объекта. Город "Сухой Лог" или фирма "Красная Заря", безусловно, отвечают на один вопрос и являются составным названием. Но приведенные вами примеры, на мой взгляд, не названия; названиями являются "Александровский" и "Великая Отечественная".

С Александровским постом все довольно прозрачно: если бы это сочетание стало единым географическим названием, то вторая его часть тоже писалась бы с заглавной буквы.